# ¿Comó comparar dos fechas en Javascript únicamente por la fecha?

Tags: javascript

Hola tengo el siguiente inconveniente, tengo un conjunto de pares de fechas provenientes de diferentes eventos, las cuales deseo comparar con una fecha especifica.

Para los tipos **Date**, *Javascript* soporta los operadores `>, <, ===, !==, >=, <=` para la comparación compara la fecha completa incluyendo fecha y horas que es lo correcto pero, aquí es donde surge mi problema ya que solo estoy necesitando comparar únicamente las fechas sin contemplar la hora.

Simplifico el problema en un ejemplo sencillo:

```
let inicio = new Date('2017-09-06T20:56:51'); 
let fin = new Date('2017-09-06T20:56:53');

// fecha a comparar si se encuentra en el rango
let comparador = new Date('2017-09-06T12:56:53');

// aqui es el problema
let resultado = inicio <= comparador && fin >= comparador
```

Si comparara únicamente por fechas omitiendo la hora, `resultado` devolvería `true`.

Comment: Agrega un ejemplo de los datos que tienes, lo que haz intentado, las fechas con la hora y un ejemplo de las fechas que queires comparar

Comment: Ahí subí un ejemplo la verdad la cantidad de votos negativos me parece de mala gana, se puede criticar mi pregunta por estar incompleta, pero sobre las respuestas me parece descortés hacia los que intentan responder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sabiendo que un día son 24 * 3600 * 1000 milisegundos, puedes tomar el valor UNIX Time de cada fecha para obtener el número de días pasados desde el origen, ignorando el resto (los decimales):

```js
let date= new Date();
let dayInMillis=24*3600000;

function compareDates(date1,date2) {
  // Nos quedamos con los días completos pasados desde el 1 de enero de 1970
  let days1=Math.floor(date1.getTime()/dayInMillis);
  let days2=Math.floor(date2.getTime()/dayInMillis);
  // comparamos los días
  if (days1>days2) {
    return 1;
  } else if (days1<days2) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}

// prueba comparando dos fechas con al menos 300 milisegundos de diferencia
setTimeout(()=> {
  let date2= new Date();
  console.log(compareDates(date,date2));
},300);
```

La función comparadora sigue el estándar: devuelve 1 si el primer parámetro es mayor que el segundo, 0 si son iguales y -1 si el segundo parámetro es mayor que el primero

Comment: Motivo del voto negativo?

Comment: Han votado negativo todos :S

Comment: Yo entiendo que lo que tiene el es un formato de año, mes, dia y horas y solo quiere comparar lo que seria la fecha (año/mes/dia).
Lo que tiene: "fecha completa incluyendo fecha y horas".
Lo que necesita: "fechas sin contemplar la hora".

Comment: @GDP No fui el único que votó negativo

Comment: En negrita hace una clara referencia a la clase Date, no entiendo las dudas

Comment: @PabloLozano Listo, dígamos que es claro con los formatos solo por usar negrita en la palabra Date, el autor tampoco es que muestre mucho esfuerzo en lo que ha intentado y en lo que está fallando

Comment: Supongo que no a todos nos cuesta entender una pregunta.

Comment: No puedo hacer nada con la esquisites de algunos usuarios, pero por suerte la mayoría de las personas no son tan exigentes y en todo caso la pregunta es la que debe ser castigada no los intentos de respuesta (que pensara que responden por ganar puntos), lo bueno es que no son moderadores sino casi no se podría hacer preguntas o responder a las mismas, por no tener suficiente detalle para algunos elitistas.

Comment: Es irracional dar -1 sólo porque hayan dado respuestas particulares a un planteamiento general, muy irracional. Deberías deshacer eso y reflexionar sobre tus criterios de evaluación

Answer (score 1):

Hay varios métodos en Javascript que te permiten "partir" las fechas, es decir, te manda un valor numérico entero. Lo que se me ocurre es que hagas la comparación 3 veces: primero el año, luego el mes y por último el día. Te dejo un ejemplo tomado de https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp

```
var d = new Date();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.getFullYear(); //Esto te devuelve el año entero como un número de 4 dígitos
var d2 = new Date();
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML=d2.getFullYear();
//Aquí pones tu comparación de años y si son iguales, pasaríamos a la siguiente comparación
if (d==d2){
var d = new Date();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.getMonth(); //Esto te devuelve el mes como un número de 0 a 11 donde 0 es Enero, 1 es Febrero y así sucesivamente
var d2 = new Date();
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML=d2.getMonth();
}
    //Haces tu comparación aquí y si los meses son iguales, pasas a la siguiente comparación
if (d==d2){
 var d = new Date();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.getDate(); //Esto te devuelve el día de 1 a 31
var d2 = new Date();
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML=d2.getDate();
}
```

Espero te haya sido de utilidad. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Estaba pensando en alguna respuesta mas larga, pero creo que lo mas sencillo para tu pregunta va a ser poner las horas a 0. De esta manera solo compararas las "fechas" como tu dices.

```js
/*DECLARO LAS FECHAS*/

var hoy, otrodia, texto;
hoy = new Date();
otrodia = new Date();
otrodia.setFullYear(2100, 0, 14);

/*CONVIERTO LAS FECHAS*/

hoy.setHours(0,0,0,0);
otrodia.setHours(0,0,0,0)

if (otrodia > hoy) {
    texto = "otro dia es mayor que hoy";
} else {
    texto = "hoy es mayor que otro dia";
}

console.log(hoy);
console.log(otrodia);
console.log(texto);
```

Comment: Coincido que es lo mas practico y rápido poner horas a 0, aunque el problema seria que tendría que modificar las variables

Comment: Podria crear unas temporales e igualarlas, que use solo para esto.

Answer (score 0):

Crea el `Date` usando solo Y/m/d luego comparas, aun así tendrás problemas para los casos == , === , !=, !== La Solución es agregar "+" delante de variables al comparar, Asi:

```js
var tuDate1 = new Date('2017-09-06T20:56:51'); 
var tuDate2 = new Date('2017-09-06T20:56:53');

var a = new Date(tuDate1.getFullYear(),tuDate1.getMonth(),tuDate1.getDate());
var b = new Date(tuDate2.getFullYear(),tuDate2.getMonth(),tuDate2.getDate());

console.log(+a > +b);//false
console.log(+a < +b);//false
console.log(+a == +b);//true
```

Cambia las fechas para mas pruebas.

El signo `+` es necesario debido a que los `Date` son objetos y jamas pueden ser iguales en comparaciones estrictas, poner el `+a == +b` es equivalente a poner `a.valueOf() == b.valueOf()`

Espero te sirva, Suerte

Comment: tienes razón, para comparaciones `!=, ==, !==, ===` es necesario usar  `Date.getTime()`

Comment: Claro también es un equivalente  +a, a.valueOf, a.getTime