# Fecha con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

Necesito hacer comparacion de una fecha que tomo de sql con l fecha actual, la fecha que recibo esta en este formato `2022-02-10` y estoy sacando la fecha actual con Js, pero me sale de esta manera `Thu Feb 10 2022 11:45:05 GMT-0800 (hora estándar del Pacífico)`. Como puedo hacer que sea el mismo formato para asi hacer la comparacion de `fecha1` y `fecha2`.
Este es el codigo que esto ejecutando:

```
var date = new Date();
console.log(date);
```

Comment: Para ti, qué hace una fecha igual a otra? Cuál es el criteria? Sólo los días; días y horas; días horas y minutos; días horas minutos y segundos; días horas minutos segundos milisegundos; días horas minutos segundos milisegundos nanosegundos?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Comó comparar dos fechas en Javascript únicamente por la fecha?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/100320/com%c3%b3-comparar-dos-fechas-en-javascript-%c3%banicamente-por-la-fecha)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Esta forma debería funcionarte

```
var todayDate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
console.log(todayDate);
```

La parte importante de este código es:

- [`toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) que devuelve la fecha en formato `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`
- `slice(0,10)` que corta la cadena en 10 caracteres desde el carácter 0 (de ese modo se queda sólo en `YYYY-MM-DD`)

Comment: Aunque esta respuesta puede servir para resolver el problema, ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido. Por favor, lee [answer] y edita tu respuesta para añadir más detalles (p.e. una breve descripción de lo que hace el código y/o cómo soluciona el problema). De ese modo podrá ser de más ayuda para otros usuarios.

Comment: Debido a su extensión? Creo que mejor explicado en tan pocas líneas es imposible. Me he leído lo que dices de Cómo responder, pero me he quedado igual, sigo sin entender el porque se ha votado negativamente la contestación.

Comment: Hola @Tomas, inicialmente la respuesta era sólo código sin ninguna descripción, algo que hacía que la respuesta se considere de baja calidad. Los votos negativos fueron de antes de que yo hiciera la edición añadiendo cómo funciona el código. Puedes ver el historial de ediciones pulsando en el enlace de "editada el..."